# Is it possible to format Chemnum to align the replacement text right?

Tags: latex

I would like to make it so the replaced text from \cmpd is flushed with the text label of each compound. Flushing TMP1 to right in ChemDraw results in the label not aligning, as the replacement begins where 'T' is.

Is it possible to define where the replacement begins or tell it to put the label at the end of the TMP indicator rather at the start? I am aware that I could define a new label as a single letter followed by a number, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this in the preamble.

Here is the file for the MWE

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2X55JeEfc410zdeACdpjGrhxqrs2tPY/view?usp=sharing

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage{tikz}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{CHOL}
    \replacecmpd{ERG}
    \replacecmpd{LAN}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{MWE.eps}
    \label{fig:MWE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like in ChemDraw
[image: This is what it looks like in ChemDraw]
But when it is compiled it is not right-aligned.
[image: But when it is compiled it is not right-aligned.]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] including a documentclass and the necessary files to compile your code?

Comment: Updated - thank you for the tip. If linking via google drive is not appropriate please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play around with the `pos` option:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage{tikz}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \replacecmpd[pos = br]{CHOL}
    \replacecmpd[pos = br]{ERG}
    \replacecmpd[pos = br]{LAN}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{MWE.eps}
    \label{fig:MWE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. 
The [pos = r] option here seems to have the desired effect, except for some reason I am now getting 'chemnum' written above the figure. I have updated the question to include an image of the output.

Comment: I have made a new question for an issue that I ran into
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805121/using-pos-option-in-chemnum-changes-the-size-of-some-labels